# AWS Amplify AppSync Login using Google user that's created in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Hi I created an AWS Amplify project with React, and GraphQL. It looks like Appsync offers a UI playground to play with GraphQL queries. I created my GraphQL API to use AWS Cognito Userpool for Authorization and I am using Google Federation login. How can I use the Google user that Cognito creates with Appsync's GraphQL API playground? The login modal shows clientID, userID and password but Google user that cognito creates after a federation login doesn't have a password right?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That playground doesn't support users federated through a social provider to the user pool, only usernames and password that are created in the user pool.